# Jquery copy attributes

Tags: jquery

I google it up but didn' find something like this.

I am having an iframe with 2 main attributes src=# and link=http://somesite.com

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="#" link="https://somesite.com?id=x&anotherid=y" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:99%; min-width:80%; height:99%; min-height:80%; padding:0px;"></iframe>
```

I load that iframe in HTML from some php script but i don't want to load the page thats why i used # as source, now when i click a button on the site it will load the iframe (if it was not loaded from a previous click), my temporary solution was:

```
<input type="button" value="load" onClick="var fr = document.getElementById('myiframe');if(fr.src.substr(-1)=='#'){fr.src=document.fr.getAttribute('link')};" />
```

Now I had a little time to implement the jQuery and I whant to know if there is some simple code in jQuery to copy from an attribute to another, or if there is a better solution to accomplish this.

something like this:
    $('#myiframe').attr('src', attr('link'));

i know the folowing will work

```
$('#myiframe').attr('src', attr('link'));
```

but i think is not to much to select the same element twice. (I am kind of an optimizer maniac :) )

or you think that I have to use a function:

```
$('#myiframe').attr('src', function(){
    ...
});
```

My question is what is the best way to achieve this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to select the element twice - cache it.

```
var $myiframe = $('#myiframe');
$myiframe.attr('src', $myiframe.attr('link'));
```

I don't think <strike>`$('#myiframe').attr('src', attr('link'));`</strike>  will work.

You should be able to do it with a function as well:

```
$('#myiframe').attr('src', function () {
    return $(this).attr('link');
});
```

Also, as a side note - try to avoid using the `onclick=` attribute. Just bind yourself in jQuery to the click event like this:

```
$('input[type=button][value=load]').click(function () {
    // One of the solutions above
});
```

Comment: Would this work with multiple elements? ie if $('#myiframe') returned a set of 10?  I believe the second solution would, but not the first

Comment: From the jquery docs: "It's important to note that the .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set."

Comment: Sameer - $('#myiframe') should only ever return one element, because the hash denotes an id - and ids should be unqiue in a given page, otherwise you have defective html.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can get more efficient than this:

```
var fr = $('#myiframe');
if (fr.attr('src').slice(-1) === '#') {
  fr.attr('src', fr.attr('link'));
}
```

*Note:* I used `slice()` instead of `substr()` because IE does not support negative `start` values.